# Using a Flask page inside of the HTML-iframe block

Tags: python, html, flask, iframe

I've created a Flask. It works fine if I use a direct link to Flask pages HTTP://flask_host:flask_port/.

If I'm using the same link inside of HTML iframe tags it returns an empty block (page is not showing)

```
<html>
  <body>
   <iframe src="HTTP://flask_host:flask_port/" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used to HTTP instead of HTTPS. I had seen the error inside of the browser developer console. Flask was configured by me to use the simplest ad-hoc HTTPS.
After that, I'm able to see the page inside of the iframe. [content of dynamically created iframe is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366646/content-of-dynamically-created-iframe-is-empty)